# Generate self-signed ssl certificate as a part of maven build

Tags: java, maven, ssl-certificate, keytool

there is a maven-keytool plugin that could be used to generate ssl certificate during the build, but it requires java 7 to generate it: http://mojo.codehaus.org/keytool/keytool-maven-plugin/generateCertificate-mojo.html
Are there any alternatives that could be used with java 6? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you still using Java 6? It's been EOL for some time now, and Java 8 is GA.

Comment: @chrylis Java 6 is still supported on RHEL, at least. Given that the question mentions a solution using Java 7, I think we can assume that there's a valid reason for using/supporting Java 6 for builds, and that they're not just using Java 6 because it didn't occur to them to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[keytool:generateKeyPair](http://www.mojohaus.org/keytool/keytool-maven-plugin/generateKeyPair-mojo.html) could be used to create a keystore that is valid for Tomcat to run an SSL connector.